# Debian service mysql status ERROR 1045 (28000)

Tags: mysql, debian

On Debian when I check:

`service mysql status`

The DB Starts fine, but I get some errors:

```
deb systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.3.22 database server...
deb mysqld[625]: 2020-00-00  00:00:00 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.3.22-MariaDB-0+deb10u1-log) starting as process 625 ...
deb systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.3.22 database server.
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: /usr/bin/mysql_upgrade: the '--basedir' option is always ignored
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: Looking for 'mysql' as: /usr/bin/mysql
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: Looking for 'mysqlcheck' as: /usr/bin/mysqlcheck
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: Version check failed. Got the following error when calling the 'mysql' command line client
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
deb /etc/mysql/debian-start[699]: FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

Why are these errors?
I can access mysql as root without any problems.

Comment: do you have changed the passwords ? look at  **/etc/mysql/debian.cnf**